# PySpark - grouping_id throws exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import grouping_id
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("grouping_id_example").getOrCreate()
data = [("John", "M", 25, "London", 5000),
    ("Jane", "F", 30, "Paris", 6000),
    ("Jake", "M", 45, "London", 9000),
    ("Julie", "F", 50, "Berlin", 10000)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Gender", "Age", "City", "Salary"])
grouped_df = df.groupBy("City", "Gender")
grouped_df = grouped_df.agg({"Salary": "sum"})
grouped_df = grouped_df.withColumn("grouping_id", functions.grouping_id(["City", "Gender"]))
```

This is throwing as

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['City', 'Gender'] of type <class 'list'>. 
For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Once I change the list to a string, I get

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: grouping_id() can only be used with GroupingSets/Cube/Rollup;;
```

Comment: It's written : *grouping_id() can only be used with GroupingSets/Cube/Rollup*. Did you use any of these ? No.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Explain what you have and what you want to do.

Comment: it's not clear for what purpose you are using `grouping_id`. can you explain what your are trying to do? what is the expected output?